# gapi.hangout.data changes in Shared State

Tags: google-hangouts, google-api-js-client

The API for google hangouts says the the callbacks for onMessageReceived and onStateChanged will only get called by the participant that sent a message or changed the state via submitDelta. What is the best way for the other participants to listen for those changes?

I want to have a participant app send a change via:

`gapi.hangout.data.submitDelta({'sState':locState});`

Then have all other clients update their local state.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling [setValue](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.setValue) will trigger [gapi.hangout.data.onStateChanged](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data.html#gapi.hangout.data.onStateChanged) and *all participants using the app* should be notified. Also, any participant running the app will be able to look up values as needed.

Calling [sendMessage](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data.html#gapi.hangout.data.sendMessage) will trigger [gapi.hangout.data.onMessageReceived](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.onMessageReceived) and your participant app-users will see the message (with no guarantee of fidelity, but reduced latency), but will not be able to look up the value sent later on without you building a mechanism to store it.

Hope this helps.